# Using Meteor with PhonegapBuild

Tags: cordova, meteor, phonegap-build

I have successfully built an android apk using the phonegapbuild service which points to my Meteor URL, I have tried two methods and they both work:

```
- Setting 'content in config.xml (<content src="http://MyIP:3000/" />)
- Using window.location = "http://MyIP:3000/"  in index.html
```

So now my Meteor app is working fine on mobile but I cannot understand how to access the Phonegap api ie. I don't know how to include the phonegap bits. I have seen some mention of using AppCache but I don't see how that is related to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Cordova API must be called from `index.html`, once you do `window.location = WEB_URL`, it will be in a different domain, you cannot get access to phonegap device features from remote website running in webview.

Comment: Do mean there is no way to use Meteor together with PhonegapBuild, and to access the PG api in Meteor code?

Comment: There is a complicated way you can access device API from website, but you cannot use Phonegap build, Intel XDK provides API similar to Phonegap, it has an API to execute JS from child-browser to mainview, you can load your meteor app in child-browser and have phonegap methods in mainView (index.html), use the XDK api `mainViewExecute` in meteor app to make phonegap api calls. http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493024

Comment: By 'Complicated way' do you mean using MeteorRider or similar and then building my own PhoneGap app locally?       On the XDK, do you perhaps have link to info on using this with Meteor? google gives plenty meteor-phonegap results but nothing for meteor-xdk